# Adding simple numbers in a loop C++

Tags: c++

I am using C++ for a very simple program but I can't seem to figure out what to do. I want to output the numbers in the loop and at the end of it, sum all the numbers.

What I need is the sum of all the numbers from 1 to 10 (55) to display after the loop output.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a;
   for (a=1; a<=10; a++)
   {
     cout<<a<<endl;
   }

   getch();

}
```

Comment: Do you know you don't have to use a loop to calculate that? Just for your information.

Comment: you mean you don't want to use iteration for this calculation?

Comment: @MohiniMhetre you talking to me? I mean this kind of calculation doesn't need any loop to calculate.

Comment: @user3437460 oh it's true. I thought that comment is posted by user3534350.

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
int a=0;
for (int i=1; i<=10; i++)
{
    a+=i;   //First add all the numbers (1 to 10)
}
cout<<a;    //show the result
```

Comment: Hmmm, where i use it ?

Comment: @user3534350, use it in your main function. `int main() {` then code written above.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a,sum=0;
    for(a=1; a<=10; a++)
    {
        cout<<a<<endl;
        sum=sum+a;
    }
    cout<<sum;
    getch();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is what you want..

```
int main()
{
    int myNum, answer=0;
    cin >> myNum;

    for (int x=1; x<=myNum; x++)
    {

        answer += x;
    }
    cout << "Sum of 1 to " << myNum << " = " << answer << endl; 
}
```

**Input:** `10`

**Output:** `Sum of 1 to 10 = 55`

Comment: This will print `1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10+ = 55`

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int i = 2;
    int sum = 1;
    std::cout << sum;
    while (i <= 10)
    {
        std::cout << " + " << i;
        sum += i;
        i++;
    }
    std::cout <<  " = " << sum << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int main()
{
    int total = 0;
    for (int a = 1; a <= 10; ++a)
    {
        std::cout << a << '\n';
        total += a;
    }
    std::cout << total << '\n';
    getch();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
int n=10;
int sum=0;
sum=(n*(n+1))/2;
cout<<sum;
```

or

```
int a=0;
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
a=a+i;
}
cout<<a;
```

Or you cant try this

```
void main()
{
   cout<<Fun(10);
}
int Fun(int a)
{
   if(a==0)
    return a;
   a+=fun(a-1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
#inlcude <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    int number,sum=0;
    for(int i=0; i<number; i++) {
        cout<<"i = "<<i<<endl;
        sum+=i;
    }

    cout<<"Total = "<<sum<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is better to add some comments or explanation to your answer